# How do I secure personal data on my computer when my employer installs monitoring software?

Tags: privacy, monitoring, partition, macbookpro

I have been working for a 100% virtual company for over a year, using my personal computer and I am fine with that. We were bought and now the parent company wants to add monitoring software to our personal computers. The challenge is preventing my employer from having access to non-employment related information. Another challenge is if my company gets hacked, I don't want my personal information on the dark web.

I have a Macbook Pro 2019 and am considering [adding a new APFS](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/partition-a-physical-disk-dskutl14027/20.0/mac/11.0) to house only company information and programs. Will that work if I create a separate user name and password for this new APFS?

I realize the best way is to buy a separate computer for work, however I'd rather not spend the extra money.

Comment: The best way is for the employer to supply *you* with the equipment needed to do the job you are contracted for. There are some labour law issues when the employer *requires* monitoring software on personal devices. That's not a security issue, but a legal one, but I offer this perspective to help you consider different options.

Answer (score 2):

> We were bought and now the parent company wants to add monitoring
> software to our personal computers.

That sounds completely wrong to me. Using personal devices for work is already borderline in my eyes. And I don't even see how you can guarantee your privacy. Try to get some information about that monitoring software but it probably has Teamviewer-like functionality built-in, meaning that they could literally see your screen and watch over your shoulder. I would assume the possibility exists. Let's hope they are not talking about [this nasty piece of software](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2021/sep/05/covid-coronavirus-work-home-office-surveillance).

Seems to me that your employer has a duty to provide equipment, and there are also legal considerations too, but I can 't really comment on that. At the very least, the employer must provide full disclosure about what the monitoring involves.

I am not familiar with Mac computers, but maybe a dual boot configuration is possible, so you can switch between personal and private setups and maintain isolation ?

I guess there is no trade union in that virtual company either ?

Comment: Thank you very much. I had no issue with using my personal devices, until the monitoring software came up.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to run a virtual machine that is ***solely*** for work so that all that the monitoring software sees is the VM.

Comment: @VirtualWorker - Absolutely, put your employer work on a VM if you must use your own machine! If for whatever reason this can't be done, your computer caught fire and was run over by a dump truck in the midst of a nuclear emp test.

Comment: I had not considered using a VM. I will have to look into that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you configure a separate installation of MacOS on the additional APFS volume, then files and activity on your personal MacOS will be safe from observation from the work MacOS.  The computer is essentially a dual-boot configuration when you [install MacOS on a separate APFS volume](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208891).

Comment: Does a separate install require a separate license?

Comment: IANAL but as I understand it you can install multiple copies of your version of MacOS on the same device (and can reinstall, etc. etc).  Upgrading to the next major OS version costs something, but once you've paid that the first sentence applies.  IANAL and I'm not an Apple guy so anyone don't hesitate to correct me.

Comment: I have no idea, myself, but it came to mind as a potential cost to this approach. I'll "ask different".

Comment: I spoke with Apple over the weekend. I did not discuss the multiple OS approach you were kind enough you were kind enough to share as I did not think of that at the time. I did discuss the possibility of creating a separate APFS to segregate my information. I was told depending on the software they use to monitor, I was told that may not work